# Index not used in "not like" query

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4 and having tough time with slow queries. Some of these use "like" and others use "not like" searches. For `like` searches I could resolve by using trigram indexes, but those with `not like` are a headache.

e.g.

```
select * from mytable where user_code not like 'TE%'
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says "Seq scan". How can I make Postgres use index in such cases?

Comment: So the query basically returns the whole table, except perhaps a very small part. Why is doing a sequential scan unexpected?

Comment: yes, right. When the query is select * from mytable where user_code like 'TE%' ("not" removed) then the trigram index kicks in and query runs in a snap

Comment: Anybody, pl help. The "not like" clause doesnt seem to use any index, normal or trigram. Whats the way out?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the output of **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query with `NOT LIKE` is not using any index because the optimizer decides that it is cheaper to do a sequential scan. Nothing unexpected here, it is probably much cheaper.

The condition `user_code LIKE 'TE%'` will probably keep a very small number of rows (say 1%), so it is good to find this small number by using an index.

But the query with `user_code NOT LIKE 'TE%'` will probably return a big number of rows (99% if `LIKE` returns 1%) so it is easier to do a sequential scan and just remove the 1% afterwards. If an index was used, it would have to do the index seek and then still go and read (that 99% of rows) from the table anyway, so almost the entire heap.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. In my case the ratio is different though. "not like TE%" records are about 66% . Still I think seq scan can be faster as these are double in number. So what you said is happening here